# How to shrink 3d box to 2d square in PythonOCC

Tags: python-3.x, geometry, transformation, ifc, opencascade

I am new to pythonooc And am trying to transform 3d objects to 2d...as though they were projected onto the XY plane an deduced to lines. So a cylinder becomes a circle, box becomes square and cuboid becomes rectangle. How will i do this with pythonooc

So far i have this. I am working in Jupyter notebook

```
from OCC.Display.WebGl.jupyter_renderer import JupyterRenderer, format_color
from OCC.Core.gp import (gp_Circ2d, gp_Ax22d, gp_Trsf)
from OCC.Core.BRepPrimAPI import (BRepPrimAPI_MakeBox)
from OCC.Display.WebGl import x3dom_renderer
from OCC.Extend.ShapeFactory import make_edge2d
from OCC.Core.BRepBuilderAPI import BRepBuilderAPI_Transform


# Draws a circle geometry using gp_Ax22d and radius=4
ci1 = gp_Circ2d(gp_Ax22d(), 4)
my_box = BRepPrimAPI_MakeBox(1., 2., 3.).Shape()
transform = gp_Trsf()
transformed = BRepBuilderAPI_Transform(my_box, transform)

my_renderer = JupyterRenderer(size=(900, 600))
my_renderer.DisplayShape(make_edge2d(ci1), shape_color=format_color(0, 0, 0), transparency=True, opacity=1)
my_renderer.DisplayShape(transformed.Shape(), shape_color=format_color(0, 0, 0), transparency=True, opacity=1)
my_renderer
```

I want to convert the box or similar shapes to its 2d geometries.

Comment: Maybe you are looking for HLR (hidden-line removal) rather than simple projection?
There are two algorithms in Open CASCADE Technology for this purpose `HLRBRep_Algo`, `HLRBRep_PolyAlgo`.

Comment: okay...but how do i change the code accordingly?